# Angularjs pass variable to factory from controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a basic pagination. Backend is ready and tested. Each page contains 10 activity.

```
/feed/1 -> displays 0-10
/feed/2 -> displays 10-20
/feed/3 -> displays 20-30
```

I want to start at 1 and increment page number by one (and load that page's data into page) when the button is clicked, but I can't see anything on the page when I view it. incr() also doesn't work, throws

> TypeError: t.data.push is not a function

error. (I use Gulp)

What is the problem here?

Url routing (I use ui-router's resolve feature)

```
angular.module('site.feed.routes')

.run(
  ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
      $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }
  ]
)

.config(
  ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
      });

      $stateProvider
        .state('posttest', {
          url: '/feed',
          templateUrl: 'feed.html',
          resolve: {
            data: 'PostData',
          },
          controller: 'PostController'
        });
    }
  ]
);
```

Factory

```
angular.module('site.feed').factory('PostData', ["$http", function($http) {

  return {
    getPage: function(pageNumber) {
      return $http.get('/feed/' + pageNumber).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Controller

```
angular.module('site.feed').controller('PostController', ['$scope', 'data', 'PostData', function($scope, data, PostData) {
  $scope.page = 1;
  $scope.data = data; // first page

  $scope.incr = function() {
    $scope.page++;
    PostData.getPage($scope.page).then(function(returned) {
      $scope.data.push(returned.data);
    });

  };
}]);
```

feed.html

```
<div ng-repeat="feedflow in data">
  <div ng-repeat="ehe in feedflow.feed">
    {{feedflow.id}}
    {{ehe.status}}
  </div>
</div>

{{page}}
<button ng-click="incr()">Increment by one</button>
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to add the parameter to the `/feed/:count` route? And then access its value through `$stateParams.count`

Comment: @Frondor I use a function and pass its argument to $http.get (page number), isn't that what I am supposed to do? I tested backend, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to pass in you data to the factory and let it update the variable, since it'll be a reference it'll be good.

```
getPage: function(pageNumber, data) {
  return $http.get('/feed/' + pageNumber).then(function(response) {
    data.push(response.data);
  });
}
```

and when calling the `factory`

```
PostData.getPage($scope.page, $scope.data);
```

another fix is simple just remove the `then` part.

```
getPage: function(pageNumber) {
  return $http.get('/feed/' + pageNumber);
}
```

## --- explaination

since you are calling multiple then on a promise..
first being inside the service

```
then(function(response) {
   return response.data;
});
```

second being.

```
PostData.getPage($scope.page).then(function(returned) {
   $scope.data.push(returned.data);
});
```

when you attach multiple `then` each one is called one after the other.
the problem with your code is you are returning in the first `then` which prevents the 2nd to execute.. I found your first `then` useless so I asked you to remove it.. hence the 2nd fix.

First fix simply passes the `$scope.data` and since `$scope.data` will be a reference so the modifications will be reflected inside the `variable`.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?